# Error on every XHR angular request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I have an issue that seems that is not affecting the behavior of the page but I don't know what is going on.
Every time I do a XHR request I get this error.

```
TypeError: b.done is not a function
at angular-animate.js:2643
at r.$digest (angular.js:15946)
at r.$apply (angular.js:16160)
at g (angular.js:10589)
at T (angular.js:10787)
at XMLHttpRequest.w.onload (angular.js:10728)
```

I'm using angular 1.4.8
Thanks in advance

Comment: does the angular-animate version match the angular version?

Comment: It wasn't specified in my bower.json, but I checked and the angular-animate is pointing to 1.5.0, is this the cause of the problem?

Comment: Could be - match them up and see if the  problem goes away, I've had similar unexplained errors when mismatching the main angular libraries before

Comment: I've rerun a bower install setting fixed angular versions and the problem is gone. Thank you

Comment: No worries - I'll add it as an answer, even though it was a stab in the dark :)

Comment: Who would have thought :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue can arise if the version number of `angular-animate` in your project is different to the version number of `angular`.

Make sure your `angular-animate` is version `1.4.8`.

It is good practice in my experience to make sure all of your major angular libraries are running the same version.